# How to redirected to home after successful login with Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a login page. I want my app to redirect the user to the homepage if the login is successful. Then credentials are checked with an API. My problem is, my vue page redirect the users before the credentials are successfully checked.

Seeing similar topic on the vue.js help forum, I understand I am supposed to send the login request, and then wait for the response promise to resolve. I feel like this is what i am doing, but it clearly does not wait for the response to be resolved before redirecting.

Here is my code in my vue page (the script part) . When I click the "signin" button, the `onSigninClick()` method is called :

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'SignInLayout',
  data () {
    return {
      username: null,
      password: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('TemplaterAuth', [
      'logged',
      'getUsername',
      'getJwtToken'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('TemplaterAuth', [
      'authenticate'
    ]),
    onSigninClick () {
      let creds = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }
      this.authenticate(creds).then(response => {
        console.log(this.getUsername)
        console.log(this.getJwtToken)
        console.log('logged:')
        console.log(this.logged)
        this.$router.push('/')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and my `authenticate()` method :

```
export function authenticate (context, creds) {
  let requestConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  Vue.http.post(
    url + apiPaths.auth,
    creds,
    requestConfig
  ).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(data => {
    context.commit('setUsername', creds.username)
    context.commit('setJwtToken', data.token)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error:')
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

When i click once the login button, my console log shows `null` for both the `username` and the `jwtToken` . Few moments later, the values are updated in the store and then I am able to login.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got my answer on the Vue forum just a few seconds after posting this : I need to `return` the promise of my `authenticate` method. So the new code is :

```
export function authenticate (context, creds) {
  let requestConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  return Vue.http.post(
    url + apiPaths.auth,
    creds,
    requestConfig
  ).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(data => {
    context.commit('setUsername', creds.username)
    context.commit('setJwtToken', data.token)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error:')
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

[Source](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-redirected-to-home-after-successful-login/41145/2?u=twistedcat)

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit fishy for me.

First: I hope, you are not using `vuex` to hold your crentials/token.
[Security tip #1](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens), [Security tip #2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/JSON_Web_Token_(JWT)_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java#Token_storage_on_client_side).

I would recommend only setting `authenticated:true` and use that for your requests.

Then:
Have a look at [global guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards) of the `vue router`, which could be leveraged, to check, whether the current user is logged in.

Last: 
To programatically route to sections of your app, you could use [router.push](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort).

So, you have to store, which route the user wanted before the login page and programmatically `push` this route afterwards.

Comment: I am already using guards and push, my problem was the redirect was happening too soon. But you are making a point that is brand new to me : what is the problem of storing the jwt token in vuex ? I read your links about security tips, and if understand it well, vuex is equivalent to localStorage, which is one of the ways recommanded in your first link. Further more, my token is encrypted, and has to be stored somewhere client side.

Comment: My bad, I have to explicitely tell vuex to store the token in localStorage. I'll do that then, thanks for the tip